# What does numbers in parenthesis means in readelf outputs?

Tags: linux, readelf

When using readelf on executables, I get a number in parenthesis after some symbols names. For instance:

```
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
 49: 00000000002052a0     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   27 stderr@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
```

There is a `(3)` after the symbol name for stderr in that case. What does this means ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww you all due respect you are plain wrong.

Comment: As phrased, this question has nothing to do with programming and development. If you want help with commands, you should ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is version symbol, where `@GLIBC_2.2.5` comes from.

The number references to the entry of `.gnu.version_r` section

ELF symbol versioning is a GNU extension to ELF. When resolving a symbol with version, if the target symbol also has version, the version must match, or the symbol can be resolved.

To maintain compatibility the version is not stored inside `.dynsym` section. Instead it is stored inside `.gnu.version` section.

`.gnu.version` has exactly same number of entries as `.dynsym` section, each entry store the corresponding symbol version (with 0 means no version requirement).

version is a string, and `.gnu.version` stores a index which references to the `.gnu.version_r` table. The number follow the symbol name is the index.

Following describes how to find the version string of a symbol:

1. assume resolving `T` symbol
2. the symbol is located at n-th entryof `.dynsym` section
3. look n-th entry of `.gnu.version` section, get the version number m
4. traverse `.gnu.version_r` section, find entry with version number m
5. the entry in `.gnu.version_r` section contains the corresponding version string (an index reference to `.dynstr` section)

**The number following symbol name is the number m**

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Do you have some documentation i can read about that ? All i find is http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_2.0.1/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/specialsections.html but it's rather scarce in information.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer with clarification about gnu.version. That's very helpful.